# PostgreSQL table design for frequent "save" action in web app

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization

Our web based app with 100,000 concurrent users has a use case where we auto-save the user's activity every 5 seconds. Consider a table like this:

```
create table essays
(
  id                 uuid not null constraint essays_pkey primary key,
  userId             text not null,
  essayparts         jsonb   default '{ }' :: jsonb,
  create_date        timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
  modify_date        timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);

create index essays_create_idx on essays ("create_date");
create index essays_modify_idx on essays ("modify_date");
```

This works well for us as all the stuff related to a user's essay such as title, brief byline. requestor, full essay body, etc. are all stored in the `essayparts` column as a JSON. For auto-saving the essay, we don't insert new rows all the time though. We update each ID (each essay) with all its components.

So there are plenty of updates per essay, as this is a time consuming and thoughtful activity. Given the auto save every 5 seconds, if a user was to be writing for half an hour, we'd have updated her essay around 360 times.

This would be fine with the "HOT" (heap only tuples) functionality of PostgreSQL. We're using v10 so we are fine. However, the challenge is that we also update the `modify_date` column every time the essay is saved and this has an index too. Which means by the principle of HOT this is not benefiting from the HOT update and a lot of fragmentation occurs.

I suppose in the web or mobile world this is not an unusual pattern. Many services seem to auto-save content. Are they insert only? If so, if the user logs out and comes back in, how do they show the records, by looking at the `max(modify_date)`? Or is there any other mechanism to leverage HOT updates while also updating an indexed column in the table?

Appreciate any pointers, thank you!

Comment: Is there any chance you could move the `modify_date` field into the JSON column as well?

Comment: We need that index for sure as it's used in various part of the app for sorting. Will it make a difference if the modify_date field was indexed from *inside* the jsonb column? I doubt it.

Comment: Well yes, it would, if you remove `modify_date` completely and instead persist that information inside the JSON, because then HOT updates would still be possible.  But, it sounds like this won't be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, challenge is that we need the index. Whether it's a column by itself or inside the JSON, the index would either be on the column or on the value inside the JSON. But the index is a must. Unless we change the table design and just do `INSERT`s, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Performing an update every 5 second with 100000 concurrent users will produce 20000 updates per second.  This is quite challenging as such, and you would need a good system to pull it off, but autovacuum will never be able to keep up if those updates are not HOT.

You have several options:

1. Choose a relational database management system other than PostgreSQL that updates rows in place.
2. Do not index `modify_date` and hope that HOT will do the trick.
3. Perform these updates way less often than once every 5 seconds (who needs auto-save every 5 seconds anyway?).
4. Auto-save the data somewhere else than in the database.